# arbitrary precision addition using lists of digits

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, addition, arbitrary-precision

What I'm trying to do is take two lists and add them together like each list is a whole number.

```lisp
(define (reverse lst)
 (if (null? lst)
  '()
  (append (reverse (cdr lst)) 
      (list (car lst)))))

(define (apa-add l1 l2)
  (define (apa-add-help l1 l2)
    (cond ((and (null? l1) (null? l2)) '())
      ((null? l1) (list (+ (apa-add-help '() (cdr l2)))))
      ((null? l2) (list (+ (apa-add-help (cdr l1) '()))))

      ((>= (+ (car l1) (car l2)) 10) 
       (append (apa-add-help (cdr l1) (cdr l2))               
               (list (quotient (+ (car l1) (car l2)) 10))
               (list (modulo (+ (car l1) (car l2)) 10)))) ;this is a problem

      (else (append (apa-add-help (cdr l1) (cdr l2))
                    (list (+ (car l1) (car l2)))))))

(apa-add-help (reverse l1) (reverse l2)))

(apa-add '(4 7 9) '(7 8 4))
>'(1 1 1 5 1 3)
```

I know that the problem is revolved around my recursion, I reversed the order of the lists to allow for easier process, however I can't seem to understand how to add my modulo value (carried over value) to the next object in the list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reverse` is already defined in Racket so there's no need to redefine it.

I have rewritten your code for a version that is clearer (to me, at least):

```
(define (apa-add l1 l2)

  (define (car0 lst) (if (empty? lst) 0 (car lst)))
  (define (cdr0 lst) (if (empty? lst) empty (cdr lst)))

  (let loop ((l1 (reverse l1)) (l2 (reverse l2)) (carry 0) (res '()))
    (if (and (null? l1) (null? l2) (= 0 carry)) 
        res
        (let* ((d1 (car0 l1))
               (d2 (car0 l2))
               (ad (+ d1 d2 carry))
               (dn (modulo ad 10)))
          (loop (cdr0 l1) (cdr0 l2) (quotient (- ad dn) 10) (cons dn res))))))
```

such as

```
-> (apa-add '(4 7 9) '(7 8 4))
'(1 2 6 3)
-> (+ 479 784)
1263
```

`car0`and `cdr0` are functions that help me to continue processing empty lists as a list of zeroes.

I introduced a new variable, carry, which is used to carry a value from iteration to iteration, just as you do it manually.

**EDIT 1**

The `named let` is equivalent to the following code:

```
(define (apa-add l1 l2)

  (define (car0 lst) (if (empty? lst) 0 (car lst)))
  (define (cdr0 lst) (if (empty? lst) empty (cdr lst)))

  (define (apa-add-helper l1 l2 carry res)
    (if (and (null? l1) (null? l2) (= 0 carry)) 
        res
        (let* ((d1 (car0 l1))
               (d2 (car0 l2))
               (ad (+ d1 d2 carry))
               (dn (modulo ad 10)))
          (apa-add-helper (cdr0 l1) (cdr0 l2) (quotient (- ad dn) 10) (cons dn res)))))

  (apa-add-helper (reverse l1) (reverse l2) 0 '()))
```

**EDIT 2**

The non tail-recursive version would be

```
(define (apa-add l1 l2)

  (define (car0 lst) (if (empty? lst) 0 (car lst)))
  (define (cdr0 lst) (if (empty? lst) empty (cdr lst)))     

  (define (apa-add-helper l1 l2 carry)
    (if (and (null? l1) (null? l2) (= 0 carry)) 
        '()
        (let* ((d1 (car0 l1))
               (d2 (car0 l2))
               (ad (+ d1 d2 carry))
               (dn (modulo ad 10)))
          (cons dn (apa-add-helper (cdr0 l1) (cdr0 l2) (quotient (- ad dn) 10))))))

  (reverse (apa-add-helper (reverse l1) (reverse l2) 0)))
```

Comment: Im somewhat confused on what is going on in you code, what is the loop function exactly?  And carry 0?

Comment: See my edit for the _named let_. Carry is the value above 10 that is carried over to next addition, divided by 10.

Comment: `res` is the result of the `apa-add-helper` procedure. When nothing is left to be done (lists empty, carry=0) then `res` is returned as the result. In the recursive call at the end of `apa-add-helper`, the newly calculated digit (dn) is prepended to `res` with `cons`. This allows the recursive `apa-add-helper` to be tail-recursive.

Comment: Why can't we use the built in car and cdr given to us by racket?

Comment: If you used the built in car and cdr functions you would need to check more conditions within this function. "car0" is checking if the list is null and if it's not it takes the car of it, otherwise it returns 0. Adding 0 to something will not change it's value which is why this code works as intended.